# Incorrect birthday in Facebook

Tags: facebook

How can I change/correct my birthday on my Facebook profile after it was set incorrectly? It's showing

> You can choose from one of the previous birthday you listed on your profile/timeline.

But I want to set it to another value.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has a limit to change your birthday to prevent abuse and fraud. If previously you have changed your birthday, it will list there and you can choose from there. If you have not changed and you are not able to change right now, you need to wait for sometime, it can vary from one day to one month to get enabled. If you waited long enough and still not able to change contact Facebook.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/563229410363824/):

> To prevent fraud and abuse, there's a limit to how many times you can change your birthday. If you've recently changed it, you may have to wait a full day before you can edit it again.